# Visual Basic Form Validation

Tags: visual-studio-2017

For Visual Basic how to create an alert if a user only selects a month but not a year or offense, then clicks 'submit'? There should be an error thrown and an alert on the screen, or along the side or bottom of a combobox; letting the user know they need to compete the form to submit.

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I just added the form; year with a combobox, month with combobox, and type with combobox and a submit button; so I would like maybe the boxes turn red if the user didn't select a particular category such as year, month, and offense type

Comment: It's better to include what you've tried *in your question* as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I didn't code anything yet; I just provided the form of with three labels along with combo-boxes of each label the year has 2009-2017 in the combobox; months have all the months in a combobox and Offense Type such as "theft", "Aggravated Assult" , "Rape"--> I have no code for the form so far just the design